# Argocd Connection to GITLAB repo

Tags: gitlab, argocd

I am trying to add the Gitlab repo to Argo CD but it is throwing this error.
***Unable to connect HTTPS repository: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://git.blahhh.blahh//info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" status code: 400***
I used SSH connection with a private key but still unable. Security Group has been configured adequately.

Answer (score 5):

For gitlab repos you have to pass the full repo name including .git.
like `https://gitlab.com/group/repo.git`

Comment: This helped me when getting a 301 status code with a GitLab repository. Here is the link to the [documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#repositories) where this is stated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message the Argo CD application is configured to use HTTP URL, not SSH. In order to access the repository using SSH key, you need to register SSH URL with the key and use the same URL as application source repo. E.g.

```
argocd repo add ssh://git@git.example.com:2222/repos/repo --ssh-private-key-path ~/id_rsa
```

```
argocd app create guestbook \
  --repo ssh://git@git.example.com:2222/repos/repo \ # URL must start from "ssh://"
  --path guestbook \
  --dest-namespace default \
  --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc
```

Comment: What I did, I replaced the git.example.co with the IP. and clicked on skip server verification.